# Running from Xcode 6.1 - Linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker-errors, xcode6

I am building a SpriteKit game using the Xcode 6.1 beta which I originally created using the release version of Xcode 6.0.1. I switched to 6.1 because of the corrupted sks problems in 6.0.1. Now, I am getting a runtime error on launch:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _swift_isaMask
```

I understand that this is a linker error, but what should I do to fix it? Or should I just create a new project in Xcode 6.1 and copy over my files? Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** I tried creating a completely new project using Xcode 6.1, and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem; I have cleaned my project (cmd+shift+k) and this fixed the bug.

Comment: I'm running Yosemite GM and 8.0.2 - this cleared up the issue.

Comment: This resolved my issue on Yosemite GM 2, iOS 8.1, and Xcode 6.1 6A1046a

Comment: This resolved my issue as well. I can verify this works if you're coming from 6.0 to 6.1

Comment: Sadly, this did NOT work for me, but I found something that did (see below).

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning and re-building the project did not help me. In my case, I had a class which was a simple UIViewController, implementing a datasource and delegate at the same time:

```
   public class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,
                    UIPickerViewDataSource {
      ...
```

When I removed the two protocols (UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource) and removed all methods from the class which implemented them, then I could build without an issue. I then re-added the methods only, it built, then went back to what I had before and - get this - **it built**. Ugh.

So there seems to be some issues with the Swift linker. Play around with the class in question, simplifying it until it builds, then add piece by piece back.

Answer (score 0):

What Im doing is to create sks files using XCODE 6.1, and for the rest of the work then I use XCODE 6.0.1.

If you want to change something on your sks you have to change again to 6.1. Never select a sks file running under 6.0.1

Comment: Indeed, this is what I plan on doing. Apple should seriously get a quick fix for this in the public release of Xcode 6.0.1. We shouldn't have to wait till October for a proper IDE.